# Upsell Products not visible if it's category and products category are different

Tags: magento-1.8, product-collection

Hi i'm having below categories

```
Camera
 - DSLR
 - Digital Camers

Accessories
 - Lenses
 - Memory cards
```

I've added a `product from lenses category` as a `upsell to a product from Digital cameras`. but it's not displaying in frontend.

```
It can be view able only if i add dslr as one more category for lens product.
```

Is there any way to show upsell products from entirely different category?

Comment: it should work. try to re-index and clear cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

upsell products are not based in category i guess.. It's showing from different category also. And if it is doing like this, than you can check by assigning all product to root level category.